# Iterate through rows in pandas dateframe in a cleaner way using .iterrows() and keep track of rows inbetween specific values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe in python 2.7 and I want to iterate through the rows and get the time between two types of events as well as the count of other types of events in between (given certain conditions).

My data is a `pandas.DateFrame` that looks like this:

```
     Time  Var1  EvntType  Var2
0    15    1     2         17
1    19    1     1         45
2    21    6     2         43
3    23    3     2         65
4    25    0     2         76 #this one should be skipped
5    26    2     2         35
6    28    3     2         25
7    31    5     1         16
8    33    1     2         25
9    36    5     1         36
10   39    1     2         21
```

Where I want to disregard rows where `Var1` equals 0 and then count the time between events of type 1, and the events of type 2 (except where `Var1 == 0`) inbetween the events of type 1. So in the above case:

```
Start_time: 19, Time_inbetween: 12, Event_count: 4
Start_time: 31, Time_inbetween: 5, Event_count: 1
```

I'm doing this in the following way:

```
i=0
eventCounter = 0
lastStartTime = 0
length = data[data['EvntType']==1].shape[0]
results = np.zeros((length,3),dtype=int)
for row in data[data['Var1'] > 0].iterrows():
    myRow = row[1]
    if myRow['EvntType'] == 1:
        results[i,0] = lastStartTime
        results[i,1] = myRow['Time'] - lastStartTime
        results[i,2] = eventCounter
        lastStartTime = myRow['Time']
        eventCounter = 0
        i += 1
    else:
        eventCounter += 1
```

which gives me the desired result:

```
>>> results[1:]
array([[19, 12,  4],
       [31,  5,  1]])
```

But this seems really circumvent and takes a long time on large dataframes. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the rows where `Var1` equals 0 using:

```
df = df.loc[df['Var1'] != 0]
```

Then create a boolean mask which is True where `EvntType` is 1:

```
mask = df['EvntType']==1
# 0     False
# 1      True
# ...
# 9      True
# 10    False
# Name: EvntType, dtype: bool
```

find the `Time`s associated with rows where the `mask` is True:

```
times = df.loc[mask, 'Time']
# 1    19
# 7    31
# 9    36
# Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

and also find the ordinal index where the `mask` is True:

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
# array([1, 6, 8])
```

The `start_time`s are all the values in `times[:-1]`.

```
In [56]: times[:-1]
Out[56]: 
1    19
7    31
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

The `time_inbetween` are the differences in times, `np.diff(times)`

```
In [55]: np.diff(times)
Out[55]: array([12,  5])
```

The `event_count` is the differences in `idx`, minus 1.

```
In [57]: np.diff(idx)-1
Out[57]: array([4, 1])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'EvntType': [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'Time': [15, 19, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 31, 33, 36, 39],
                   'Var1': [1, 1, 6, 3, 0, 2, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1],
                   'Var2': [17, 45, 43, 65, 76, 35, 25, 16, 25, 36, 21]})

# Remove rows where Var1 equals 0
df = df.loc[df['Var1'] != 0]

mask = df['EvntType']==1
times = df.loc[mask, 'Time']
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)

result = pd.DataFrame(
    {'start_time': times[:-1],
     'time_inbetween': np.diff(times),
     'event_count': np.diff(idx)-1})

print(result)
```

yields

```
   event_count  start_time  time_inbetween
1            4          19              12
7            1          31               5
```

Comment: Using the index to count, so simple and elegant, thanks a lot!

Comment: I usually use `data = data[data['Var1']!=0].reset_index(drop=True)` to remove rows and reset the index, that way you could use the index directly, but `np.flatnonzero()` works too.